# Logarithm roots

Tags: calculus, logarithms, roots

Given an equation 
$$\ln(1 - a^x + b^x - (5 \, a)^x + (5 \, b)^x) = a \, x,$$
where $a,b > 0$, $a \neq b$ and real valued, it is evident that the can be placed into the form
$$\ln(1 +(b^x - a^x)(1 + 5^x)) = a \, x$$
and when $x = 0$ the equation yields a solution. Now, since $ax$ is a linear line and $\ln(1+f(x))$ is a curved line there will be a second solution.

**The Question:**

What is a method, which is not numerical, to find a second root of the given equation?

Comment: are $a$ and $b$ just real numbers? Is there any additional information about $a,\,b$?

Comment: @mdave16 Yes, an edit has been made. $a,b$ can be considered as integers, mainly, but fractional values could also work. In general, $a = b =0$ also yields a solution, but is the same result as $x=0$.

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced there is always a second solution, do you have an argument for the existence of the second root? (I'm fixing values of $a,\,b$ and solving for $x$, I assume this is what you want) At least not sure about second *real* solution. (I'm looking at $a = 2$, $b = 3$)

Comment: @mdave16 For $a=2, b=3$ then $\ln(1 + (3^x-2^x)(1+5^x)) = 2x$ and Wolfram Alpha yields $x=0, x=1.06678$. Another example $a=1, b=2$ WA yields $x=0, -0.7424$ and so on.

Comment: Note that your reasoning might be flawed (in general, not in this case). Just because $ax$ is a linear function, and has one intersection with a curve, this does not mean that they will have a second intersection. It can also be a tangent point, meaning that the derivatives in that point are also the same. This will then mean that the curve and line will move away from each other and only "touch" in the point $x=0$. Think for example of the functions $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=\log(x+1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to get approximate solutions for certain ranges of $a$ and $b$.  The idea is to solve the equation using power series centered at $x=0$.

**The Result**:  Suppose $b$ satisfies $\epsilon=ae^{a/2}/b-1\ll 1$, and that $a$ satisfies $g(a)=O(1)$, where
$$
g(a)=-\frac{(a-\ln 5) (a-\ln 25)+\ln (a) (4 \ln (5 a)-6 a)}{a (a-\ln(25a^4))^2}.
$$
Then
$$
x=-\frac{2\epsilon}{a}\frac{a-\log (25a^4)}{\log^2 \left(5 a^2e^{-\frac{a}{2}}\right)}+O(\epsilon^2).
$$
**Verification**:  Choose $a=1$.  Then $g(a)=-1.64$ is $O(1)$, and the approximation should work.  If $\epsilon=.01$, then the exact answer is
$$
x=0.0358809.
$$
The approximation obtained using the above formula is
$$
x\approx 0.0360543.
$$
So, not bad.  Below, I show where this comes from.

**--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**Derivation**: Let $f(x)=ax-\ln(1+(b^x-a^x)(1+5^x))$.  Assume that $x>0$ is small and $f(0)=f(x)=0$.  Then Taylor's theorem gives
$$
0=xf'(0)+x^2f''(0)/2+x^3f'''(0)/6+O(x^4).
$$
Let us assume that $f''(0)\neq 0$.  Then
$$
x=-\frac{2f'(0)}{f''(0)}-\frac{f'''(0)}{3f''(0)}x^2+O(x^3).
$$
The hope is that $2f'(0)/f''(0)$ is small and that the quadratic and cubic terms are negligible.  That is, we want $f'''(0)x^2/[3f''(0)]\ll x$, or if $x\approx 2f'(0)/f''(0)$, for
$$
\frac{2f'''(0)f'(0)}{3f''(0)^2}\ll 1.
$$
If this condition is known to be satisfied, then we obtain:
$$
x=-\frac{2f'(0)}{f''(0)}+O(\frac{f'(0)^2}{f''(0)^2})
$$
which yields an approximate solution in the limit of $\frac{f'(0)}{f''(0)}\to 0$.  Whether these smallness conditions are true depends on $a$ and $b$.

Now, for your $f$, we have
\begin{align}
f'(0)&=a+2\ln(a/b),\\
f''(0)&=2\ln(a/b)\ln(5a^3/b),\\
f'''(0)&=3\ln(a/b)[\ln (a^5)\ln(5b^2/a^2)+\ln (5)\ln(5/b^3)].
\end{align}
Suppose $b=ae^{a/2}/(1+\epsilon)$ for some small $\epsilon\ll 1$.  This choice makes $f'(0)=-2\epsilon+O(\epsilon^2)$ small, so it's natural.  If you let Mathematica do the algebra, then you can show that
$$
\frac{f'''(0)f'(0)}{f''(0)^2}=\epsilon g(a)+O(\epsilon^2),
$$
where $g$ is as above.  Provided that $g(a)\approx O(1)$, the smallness condition is satisfied, and we obtain the approximate solution.  Expanding $-2f'/f''$ to first order in $\epsilon$ gives the desired expression above.